# How to use diff and patch in Cygwin on Windows?

Tags: cygwin, diff, patch

I follow many articles out there but I still don't know how to use diff and patch in Cygwin

Here I create 2 files in Windows Explorer

**origin.txt**

```
one
two
three
```

**new.txt**

```
one
four
five
```

Then I `diff -u origin.txt new.txt > file.patch` which results this

```
--- origin.txt  2013-03-21 15:53:20.062956800 +0700
+++ new.txt 2013-03-21 15:53:29.191869600 +0700
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 one
-two
-three
\ No newline at end of file
+four
+five
\ No newline at end of file
```

Then I `patch origin.txt < file.patch` which show errors

```
patching file origin.txt
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file origin.txt.rej
```

How to overcome this? Is this related to Unix and Windows file format?

**P/S**: I'm using CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 and Windows 7 64bit

Comment: If you don't have `patch` installed, use: `apt-cyg install patch`. (in its own package called `patch`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly a line-ending problem. You can fix this by running `dos2unix` over the files first:

```
$ dos2unix origin.txt new.txt
$ patch origin.txt < file.patch
patching file origin.txt
```

Comment: So before diff and patch, we do **dos2unix**, then after that, we **unix2dos** ?

Comment: @entropy: Yes. Or, ideally, stick to keeping it in Unix format at all times.